# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Please review: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17677/is-dreamtemplate-com-good

I wrote a comment below the question. I don't understand why this was closed. I'm asking on this website to use other webmaster's experience. I'm looking for unbiased advice (in contrast to seemingly fake reviews I found online).

I'm a webmaster looking for webmaster help, this is supposed to be the place for it.

Also, the user who closed it didn't even write any comments.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is opinions and experiences. That does not meet the criteria for a good question as set forth in the [faq](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/faq). Questions like yours are better suited for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) where subjective discussions can occur.

Comment: I asked if this is a scam, and this is valid HTML/CSS. That's hardly subjective. I'm asking if someone used it before and if it worked. Facts - not opinions.

Comment: I can reword the question to make it clearer if you want.

Comment: Asking for experiences, including if something is a scam, is subjective and not the kind of questions the StackExchange family of sites wants to encourage. You can use Google to find out if they are a scam. It's also not possible to answer if the templates are valid HTML/CSS because every template is different and no one has seen every template.

Comment: I googled before going here, and came here at the end because I don't trust the links on google. I trust the people on StackExchange. The whole point of StackExchange is to use the experience of others to help us make better decisions. The other StackExchange sites are filled with such questions, and are very popular. First time I got shut down for this. Not cool. If I get scammed by those people, I blame you.

Comment: @nute soliciting opinions isn't within the scope of Stack Exchange per the [faq]